# Compatibility between dotnetcore and framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm adding a new dotnetcore (RC2) project to my existing solution which contains a set of dotnet framewotk 4.5 projects.

When I try to add a reference in my brand new dotnetcore project I get a message telling me that I can't do a reference from a project that targets framework 4.5.

> The following projects are not supported references: "project name"
>   has target frameworks that are incompatible with targets in current
>   project "project name"

I followed this [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/45) but I didn't find any clear solution for the issue.

what's the recommended approach for this situation?

Comment: Are you creating a class library or an application (ASP.NET Core / Console Application)?

Comment: Just as a small summary: By default, .NET Core assemblies target `netstandard1.5` or `netcoreapp1.0` moniker, this means ASP.NET 4.6.1 as minimum. First thing would be to target a lower version of the framework (only works in class libraries though, i.e. netstandard1.2 for .NET 4.5.1/2). Then the old projects may not understand the netstandard moniker (not sure of it,never tested) and in this case you'd have to create a target within the framework section which targets `net451`.  when *.xproj  project compiles,it creates one nuget package per target, 1 net451 and 1 netstandard. reference these

Comment: Hi, yes I'm creating a MVC dotnetcore app, is there a way to upgrade my projects from 4.5.* to 4.6.* and then do the reference from my dotnetcore app?

Comment: Well technically you can either run your own nuget server (or just a network share) and add this to your feed and put your compiled nuget packages there and then fetch it via nuget. In case the legacy csproj don't recognize your project, you can add `net451` as target, this creates two binaries inside the nuget package (for netlibrary/netcoreapp and for net451). If that's more hustle then you like to have, you can still create a csproj file in your .xproj class library. Then you should be able to reference it like before

Answer (score 1):

Replace your library's project file with a new [`Class Library (Portable)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx) project (PCL). Once there, you can target a PCL profile or the new [`Net Standard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-target-the-net-standard)

You can also have 2 separated project files, building the same source files, but each one targeting a different frameworks/target (one for PCL, one for .NET fw).

Here you have a step-by-step: https://oren.codes/2016/06/23/portable-is-dead-long-live-netstandard/