# The type or namespacename 'myNamespace' could not be found. .Net Core 1.0.1 and .Net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am having an issue building my .Net Core 1.0.1 Web API while using an older .Net Framework 4.5.1 assembly. I get the error "The type or namespacename 'myNamespace' could not be found". Below is the project.json snippet that should allow me to load the project and Visual Studio 2015 does not throw a design time error for the method call I am trying to use. I only get the error at compile time.

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+8"
        ],
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "type": "platform",
                "version": "1.0.1"
            }
            "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.3.0"
        }
    },
    "net451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "myNamspace": {
                "target": "project"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is not a cross platform system. This will be on a windows server only.

Comment: You won't be able to reference .NET Framework assembly from .NET Core project based on .NET Core. I would get rid of netcoreapp1.0 section from frameworks section and let it run under 4.5.1 only.

Comment: @Zbigniew Evertthing I am reading says I should be able to do this. It may be a bug seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/688), I am not sure. Core is supposed to work with other frameworks from what i understand and have read. If not can you refer me to some documentation that says it does not?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1672

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add .NETFramework 4.5 dll to .NETCore project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731567/add-netframework-4-5-dll-to-netcore-project)