# Can .Net 4.6 run on linux

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core

I am upgrading a web project from DotNet 4.6 to DotNetCore 2.0, and I intend to run this application on Linux. I would like to postpone upgrading some of the code to DotNetCore - such as referenced DLLs. I found that you can reference older DLLs in DotNetCore in this answer

[Add .NETFramework 4.5 dll to .NETCore project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731567/add-netframework-4-5-dll-to-netcore-project).

But, I am guessing this will not allow me to run on Linux? Is that right? Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You possibly can run such DLLs on Linux if they don't contain any windows platform specific references (WinForm, WPF, WCF, XAML, COM):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyfDG4mjBPk
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOzcVwzkGP0

Comment: This is not the only limitation. The assemblies you reference **must not use** any API which is unavailable in .NET Standard 2.0! Basically, the ability to reference .NET 4.5 libraries in .NET Core / .NET Standard is useless and limited to libraries which don't any non-.NET Core 2.0 API and were not ported yet for `netstandard2.0` (i.e. abandoned/orphaned libraries, where it's unexpected to ever get an official update cause they are not maintained actively anymore)

Comment: you're right, because of the limitation, there are some more APIs which are not available on Linux. 
It's not really useless, if you need to use old libraries and don't have the chance to port them. I use it while porting LightCore (https://github.com/juergengutsch/lightcore) to .NET Standard 2.0 and by also supporting old usages and frameworks

Comment: My particular DLLs contain business layer and utility-type code. I am not using any Windows-specific APIs that I know of. Obviously, early testing is my friend.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr: You should install the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer) VS 2017 extension, then run it against the assembly you want to use with .NET 2.0/.NET Standard 2.0 profile. If it shows any unavailable API, you will likely run into troubles using it and will need to port it to .NET Standard 2.0 first or make sure the API is not called from your code (not as easy unless you have access to the source, but then you can easily compile it to .NET Standard 2.0)