# Is it possible to use the .Net Framework 4.5 Dll reference in .Net Core Console App that will run in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I have a DLL(Say FileWrapper.dll) that is build using .Net Framework 4.5 (Build for linux)

Is it possible to build a console application (in .Net Core 2.2 - For Linux) that has references FileWrapper.dll and use various functions within in FileWrapper.dll.

Any pointers or past experience is helpful.

Building .net core 2.2 console app for Linux using dll build in .Net Framework 4.5

No Code specific

Hoping to build .net core console app that uses a dll build in .net framework 4.5

Comment: Depending on what it does, possibly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps#net-framework-compatibility-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can .Net 4.6 run on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508989/can-net-4-6-run-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible and was introduced with the .NET standard 2.0 which is supported by .Net Core 2 and .Net Framework 4.6.1.  The concept is described is called a "compatibility shim" in .Net Standard 2.0. Here are a couple of links to get you started

[Building a Compatibility Shim with .Net Standard 2.0](https://espressocoder.com/2018/09/28/building-a-shim-with-net-standard-2-0/)

[stack overflow - Compatibility shim used by .Net Standard 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464937/compatibility-shim-used-by-net-standard-2-0)