# Using System.Management on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, wmi, .net-5, .net-4.6

I am creating a console .NET 5.0 app to communicate with a KUKA Robot using dll's provided within their WorkVisual software. These dll's were built with .NET Framework 4.6. On Windows everything works as expected.

The tricky part is I need to port it to Linux. As .NET 5.0 seems to be cross-platform, I decided to build my app with .NET 5.0 and add Kuka dll's (.NET 4.6) as References. While on Windows it works well, the problem starts on Linux. The app itself runs using .NET 5.0 runtime (`dotnet MyApp` from terminal) but only so long I try calling a function which connects to the robot. Then I get an exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentationClassAttribute' from assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctorWithParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.IsDefined(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ShowInStackTrace(MethodBase mb)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat, StringBuilder sb)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
   at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Exception.ToString()
...
```

I have already added NuGet packages to my project:

- System.Management
- Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

but none of them helped. I am curious whether it's possible to run the app using these dll's on Linux and if so, what do I need to do more to make it work.

I have no influence on the dll's as they are compiled, I have no source code and can only use them as they are.

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508989/can-net-4-6-run-on-linux. But I don't have much hope.. those external dll's might well rely on certain functionality that isn't supported on linux(

Comment: @Driven-it thank you, I've tried .NET Portability Analyzer as suggested in one of the comments, but despite showing 100% portability of my solution with all .NET Core/Standard and also with Mono, it also showed that the dll's provided by Kuka's workvisual were "unresolved assemblies" and were not checked at all... So didn't quite resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` nuget is nuget package to provide access to APIs in .NET Framework that mostly runs on Windows only (hence the "Windows" as part of the nuget's name).

The Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility nuget package is also actually a metapackage that provides list of related APIs that are available in .NET Framework. This also includes `System.Management` nuget package and others Windows only such as `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`.

Therefore it is not guaranteed to run on other OS beside Windows, especially those packages that needs interop with Windows, such as System.Management and Microsoft.Win32.Registry.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately this reaffirms what I feared... But still the question is - is there any way to avoid the issue? Maybe by using wine or something?

Comment: using Wine? I don't know about the possibility and I'm not sure . Wine is a Windows emulator. Since you can't run linux binaries on Windows directly, so Wine as Windows emulator may not be able to run it.