# adding class library to web application with net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'v created  a web application with net core and with this project

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Core": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }    
  },
```

Then I've crated a class library net core with this project

```
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

but when I try to add the class project to web application, VS2015 tell me

```
The following project are not supported as reference.
WebApplication:
.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1
ClassLibrary:
.NETStandard, Version=v1.6
```

How can I add class library to main project?

Comment: use class library (package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target .NET framework 4.6.1, your class library must be **.NET Standard 1.4** or lower as suggested on official docs - [How to target the .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-target-the-net-standard)

1) Create .NET core class library. `project.json` looks like this-

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

2) In ASP.NET Core application (.NET framework), it can reference like below-

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }    
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your project as a dotnetcore project (see image below) because it seems like you want to add a framework 4.6 file to your dotnetcore application.

[image: dotnetcore project]

for more information about dotnetcore compatibulity check this post
[Compatibility between dotnetcore and framework 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842366/compatibility-between-dotnetcore-and-framework-4-5)